# Version 4 addons missing

Tags: installation

Had Blender 3.6 installed with all my addons enabled. Installed Blender 4 and said yes to all the defaults and none of my addons are showing in my preference.

Comment: Do you mean third-party addons which you've added manually or Blender's built-in ones? If third-party, make sure that they've been updated to work with the Blender 4 API by checking on the web sites where you got them originally.

Comment: Yes, they are third party ones. I think I will stick with 3.6 for now.

Comment: Just tried installing third party addons in Blender 4 and they install manually. Just a bit of a pain.

Comment: They're probably updated ones for version 4 in that case. Earlier versions would have been rejected during the Blender update.